# Try Except Else not functioning

Tags: python

With the following code. Which iterates through a list of message ids and creates the http request and then appends to json. I am having problems with exceptions. The Try except Else doesn't seem to work.

```
import urllib3
import json
import csv
from progressbar import ProgressBar
import time

pbar = ProgressBar()
base_url = 'https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/mailbox/mailMessages/'
fields = {"include_body": "1", "api_token": "token"}

json_arr = []
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
with open('msgid.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
   for x in pbar(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')):
      while True:
          try:
              r = http.request('GET', base_url + "".join(x), fields=fields)
              break
          except Exception:
              time.sleep(1)
      mails = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
      json_arr.append(mails)
with open('JDATA.json', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    json.dump(json_arr, outfile)
```

I literally want it to skip over an error and move on to the next iteration.

but i constantly get this thrown up at random iteration numbers:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "API.py", line 23, in <module>
      mails = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
    File "C:\Users\Robert Millard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-      32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
      return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    File "C:\Users\Robert Millard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
  obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Robert Millard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
  raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
  json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: As the traceback shows, the exception is thrown in the call to `json.loads`, which is not inside the `try`.

Comment: Ah. I guess that makes perfect sense. Really should have realized that in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, but a `try/except` clause is not a loop. It may be inside a loop, but that doesn't make it a loop.

Comment: pendentry is always welcome. Changed the title.

Comment: What do you mean by "Try Except Else"? Your try clause does not have an else clause attached.